# what is the difference between GCN and random walk

Tags: neural-networks, graph-theory, random-walk, graph-neural-network

Anyone could explain to me what is the difference between graph convolutional network (GCN) and random walk? or they are the same?

Any further explanation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Graph convolutional networks are generalizations of standard convolutional networks to irregular graphs. Convolutional networks operate on regular n-dimensional matrices/tensors.

Random walk is a whole another concept. You have a starting point, and randomly choose where to among your neighbours via some set of defined probability rules. In standard 2D, it's like going towards south/north/east/west randomly some number of steps. Random walks can also be performed over graphs, since at each step, you'll choose a neighbour and iterate.